# How to tell if handset is on WiMAX

Tags: android, telephonymanager, wimax

I use TelephonyManager to get the network type as in `getNetworkType()`. Currently I see only CDMA and GSM networks only. How do I detect WiMAX as the networkType. Sprint's HTC EVO 4G phone supports WiMAX and when I use `getNetworkType()`, I get `NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A` even though the handset is on WiMAX network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [document here](https://docs.google.com/View?id=dhtsnvs6_57d2hpqtgr&pli=1#_Toc246914489_4717798056080937_012391189578920603)

Section 2.1 gives a sample and method calls to determine if the WiMax connection is enabled. This may only work for the Evo and Epic - it doesn't say if it works for the Evo Shift but my guess is that it will work fine for any Android Sprint 4G device.

Something like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
int networkType = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType();
```

Edit:
I just noticed the document states

> While 4G is the active data connection you can only detect this using the ConnectivityManager, under this condition the TelephonyManager will still reflect the status of the CDMA network which is providing voice services.  You will not see any 4G/WiMax information show up in the TelephonyManager.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for you quick reply. I tested this on Sprint's EVO 4G. I did see WIMAX as the returned value for cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName(). Do you think if I try this on an LTE handset such as the one recently released by MetroPCS (Samsung) would show LTE as the TYPE?

Comment: No this is only for Sprint 4G Devices.  Since Android (I don't think) supports 4G technology natively it must be implemented by the carrier; which is why this method only works for Sprint.  I tried to look for a MetroPCS API but couldn't find anything (yet) - if I do I'll add it to my answer for you later.  I'm going to look for a Verizon one too.

Answer (score 0):

Honeycomb API level has introduced updates to Telephony Manager including a number of new networks - be sure to filter by API 11:

int     NETWORK_TYPE_LTE    Current network is LTE
int     NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS   Current network is UMTS

Note that it will probably take at least 6 months until we start seeing this in the "wild", as new devices (Such as HTC Thunderbolt) are still shipping with Froyo. It will be interesting to see what workaround Verizon implemented in Froyo for LTE.